# one line definition of a variable conditional on the output of a logical test

Tags: bash, variable, test, assignment

In `bash` programming I've always defined conditional variables in the following long hand way

```
dog=1
if [[ $dog -eq 1 ]] ; then
   cow=1
else
   cow=0
fi
```

This is obviously incredibly inefficient.    In `MATLAB` I can do the following

```
cow=(dog==1)
```

i.e., one line instead of five.     Is there an analogous way to do this in bash?    Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Obviously, the `[[ ... test ...]]` is much more flexible in testing and in the subsequent assignment.  Are your only tests against "1/0" for dog, and with numeric assignments to "cow"?

Comment: `cow=$(( dog == 1 ))` is as close as it gets, for a boolean result.

Comment: As @Paul and @JeffSchaller showed that specific case is easy. It gets trickier if/when you want to replace `if [[ $(animal) == "dog" ]]; then cow="$(foo)"; else cow="$(bar)"; fi` (i.e. involving function calls) with `cow=( $(animal) == "dog" ? "$(foo)" : "$(bar)" )`. That last part was non-existent pseudo-code in case it's not obvious.

Comment: Thanks very much guys.    @EdMorton, I assume you're saying that there's no way to do a one-line variant of  `cow=$((dog ? 1 : 0))` with strings, e.g., it would be wonderful if this worked:    `yn=y ; cow=$((yn ? "yes": "no"))` but as you say it doesn't.     Is there some one-line variant that *does* work for strings?

Comment: @Leo with a slightly different use-case, consider asking a new question, so that the scope can be set appropriately.

Comment: @LeoSimon as Jeff says, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For purely integer-based assignments, you could use the `expr ? expr : expr` conditional operator:

```
dog=1
cow=$((dog ? 1 : 0))
```

This only works for integer values of cows and dogs, and only tests (dog, here) for zero/non-zero values.

```
dog=2
cow=$((dog ? 42 : 7))
```

Comment: This is great, mostly I'm doing binary testing and for this it's adequate, but I would like to do string testing as well, esp for single character strings like 'y' or 'n', see question above.